# Node.js SFTP ending connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sftp

I am using a sh2-sftp-client module to do a sftp get request for multiple files. I can pull the files just fine but when I try to pull more then 10 files, I get an error: `(node:4068) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 ready listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit` and `Error: (SSH) Channel open failure: open failed`.

I was doing some searching and I was able to prevent the first this issue by increasing the EventEmitter: `require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 0;`. I now this isn't the correct way to fix this because I need to close the connection after each request. But I am not sure where to add `sftp.end`.

**route.js**

```
    // Connect to server
    sftp.connect(config).then(() => {  
        //Grab file and set it as a readable stream
        sftp.get(fileName, "false", null).then((data) => {
            // This is what the file name will be
            res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + fileName);
            // Setting headers to correct MIME type to the header of the response object
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'audio/wav');
            //Pipe the respose
            data.pipe(res);
            // End connection?
            sftp.end();
        });
    }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err, 'catch error');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

When there is no more data and since data is a read stream you can do this:

`data.on('end', () => sftp.end())`

Comment: I tried adding it underneath `data.pipe(res);` but I still got the same message of a `Error: (SSH) Channel open failure: open failed`.

Comment: You should add it before the `data.pipe(res)`